# Kollar's Proposition 1.3, Chapter IV

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I was reading Kollar's book "Rational curves on algebraic varieties". This is from Chapter IV, proposition $1.3$. I don't understand the proof from $1.3.3$ to $1.3.1$, Page- 182. Suppose I have a dominant morphism $\mathbb{A}^1 \times Z \to X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, assume all are affine varieties. Also assume that for some $z \in Z$ the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \times z \to X$ is non-constant. Then how to prove there is some affine variety $Z^{\prime}$ such that $\dim(Z^{\prime}) = \dim(X) - 1$ with a dominant morphism $\mathbb{A}^1 \times Z^{\prime} \to X$. 
Any suggestion or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: If $\dim Z> \dim X-1$, you need to check that for general hyper surface $Z'\subset Z$, $\mathbb{A}^1\times Z'\to X$ remains dominant. Then you can repeat until you get desired dimension.